# Convert Dictionary into Ordered Dictionary using Specified Order

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I currently have a dictionary with six keys, and the ideal ordering of those keys are as such:

```
order_of_keys = ["id", "question", "choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4", "solution"]
```

Right now each one of those keys corresponds to a dictionary of all possible values.  The way I constructed this dictionary was through a Pandas reader (not sure if this matters, but there might be a way to resolve this through Pandas).

```
xls = ExcelFile('quiz/all_questions.xlsx')
    df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0], parse_cols = 241, keep_default_na=False, na_values=[""])
    questions_2 = df.to_dict()
```

The current structure of the dict is like so:

```
{'id': {0: 'CB_1', 1: 'CB_2'}, 'question': {0: 'Who is Ghoulsbee Scroggins?', 1: 'Who is Ebeneezer Yakbain?}, 'choice1': {0: 'Cat', 1: 'A mathematician'}, 'choice2': {0: 'Dog', 1: 'A mathematician'}, 'choice3': {0: 'Ape: 'A mathematician'}, 'choice4': {0: 'Astrophysicist', 1: 'A mathematician'}, 'solution': {0: 'Ape', 1: 'A mathematician'}
```

I would like to turn it into an Ordered Dict of the form:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('question', 'What is the capital of China?'), ('choice1', 'Shanghai'), ('choice2', 'Guangzhou'), ('choice3', 'Hong Kong'), ('choice4', 'Beijing'), ('solution', 'Beijing')]), OrderedDict([('id', '2'), ('question', 'What year did World War 1 start?'), ('choice1', '1896'), ('choice2', '1914'), ('choice3', '1921'), ('choice4', '1929'), ('solution', '1914')]), OrderedDict([('id', '3'), ('question', 'What is the second closest planet to the sun?'), ('choice1', 'Saturn'), ('choice2', 'Mercury'), ('choice3', 'Venus'), ('choice4', 'Mars'), ('solution', 'Venus')]), OrderedDict([('id', '4'), ('question', 'What is the symbol for gold on the periodic table?'), ('choice1', 'Au'), ('choice2', 'Gd'), ('choice3', 'Gl'), ('choice4', 'Or'), ('solution', 'Au')])]
```

I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over the key, value pairs in the right order to construct a list of tuples.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use an `OrderedDict` and a `for` loop.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

order_of_keys = ["id", "question", "choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4", "solution"]

input_dict = {'id': {0: 'CB_1', 1: 'CB_2'},
              'question': {0: 'Who is Ghoulsbee Scroggins?', 1: 'Who is Ebeneezer Yakbain?'},
              'choice1': {0: 'Cat', 1: 'A mathematician'},
              'choice2': {0: 'Dog', 1: 'A mathematician'},
              'choice3': {0: 'Ape', 1: 'A mathematician'},
              'choice4': {0: 'Astrophysicist', 1: 'A mathematician'},
              'solution': {0: 'Ape', 1: 'A mathematician'}}

res = []

for key in input_dict['id']:
    d = OrderedDict()
    d['id'] = key
    for k in order_of_keys[1:]:
        d[k] = input_dict[k][key]
    res.append(d)
```

**Result**

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 0),
              ('question', 'Who is Ghoulsbee Scroggins?'),
              ('choice1', 'Cat'),
              ('choice2', 'Dog'),
              ('choice3', 'Ape'),
              ('choice4', 'Astrophysicist'),
              ('solution', 'Ape')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 1),
              ('question', 'Who is Ebeneezer Yakbain?'),
              ('choice1', 'A mathematician'),
              ('choice2', 'A mathematician'),
              ('choice3', 'A mathematician'),
              ('choice4', 'A mathematician'),
              ('solution', 'A mathematician')])]
```

**Explanation**

- Create a class which subclasses `OrderedDict` and defines an empty list as the default value.
- Loop through each `id`. For each `id`, add items to an ordered dictionary aligned with the given list `order_or_keys`.
- Append each `OrderedDict` to a result list.

Comment: Absolutely incredible.  Worked perfectly! I was struggling with this for over an hour!  Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

**Ordered Dictionary remembers the order in which its contents are added keeps track of the order**. If you can't control the order of insertion, you can just reorder it by:

```
# od is your ordered dictionary

for key in reversed(order_of_keys):
    od.move_to_end(key)
```

Also just as a side note, in Python3 dictionary is ordered (although a feature you technically shouldn't rely on), so you can create a another dictionary and insert your items in desired order, it's better than ordered dictionary because ordered dict stores a linked list inside to keep track of the order, so it takes more memory.